# How to clear data solana-test-validator

Tags: anchor, solana-program, solana-cli

I want to clean `solana-test-validator` so that every time I deploy localnet the data in the program account will be recorded from the beginning

Comment: You can either use the `--reset` flag or just delete the entire ledger folder.

Answer (score 6):

You can use `solana-test-validator -r` to reset the old data and start from the beginning.

Answer (score 2):

`solana-test-validator --help` might help to answer most of your questions about it, `--reset` will work in your case.